# Motor Speed Controller Voltage Regulator

Tags: motor, induction-motor, motor-controller

Would [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2000W-AC-50-220V-25A-Adjustable-Motor-Speed-Controller-Voltage-Regulator-PWM-NEW-/172251512611?hash=item281afd7f23:g:Jc4AAOSwbYZXbBMk) cheap Chinese voltage regulator work as a speed controller for a 3 phase 300W induction motor?

thanks.

Comment: Do you know how the speed is controlled on a 3 phase induction motor? Have you at least tried to do some basic research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No that will not work.**

That "voltage regulator" is not really a voltage regulator, it is a dimmer circuit, something like this:

[image]

These circuits work very well with **resistive** loads like lightbulbs and heaters.

They do not work very well with motors.

The simplest dimmer circuits which are better optimized for motor loads usually have a large inductor which I do not see on this "regulator".

But the main issue is that your motor is **3 phase** and this dimmer is not, it is strictly 2 phase only.

You will need a proper 3-phase motor controller to adjust the speed of your 3-phase motor. If you use something else, it will either not work, blow up and generally end in tears.

Comment: I tend to disagree because in nearly all washing machines, such a "motor dimmer" is used to control the rotation speed. And they use a 300W three-phase motor with switchable terminals for the phase-shift capacitator needed to run the thing at single-phase.

Comment: *needed to run the thing at single-phase* Nowhere does OP poster say that he's using his 3-phase motor in single phase mode.

Comment: I can hardly see another use for a 300W-only 3-phase motor.

Comment: Until OP says that that is what he's doing my answer stands as it is.

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to specify that I will use a capacitor to delay one phase, and essentially us it on 240V

Comment: In that case, it will most likely work but keep in mind you are **not regulating** the speed but rather **limit the power**. At best it gives you a non-linear value->power characteristic. May be much worse. Do not expect it to run smoothly at low speeds as it heavily depends on the motor M/v characteristic too. Last note: the heat sink is too small. With 300W motor power, you have a current of ~2.5A (asynchronous motors need about the same amount of reactive power as they need as active power) and the voltage drop above a triac is about 2V, which gives you 5W thermal dissipation loss.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably not unless you are looking for changes over a very small speed range.  Induction motor speed is a function of line frequency and changing the voltage changes the speed very little.  Take a look here [Speed control of three phase machine](http://www.electrical4u.com/speed-control-of-three-phase-induction-motor/) under speed control from the stator side #2.

Answer (score 1):

No, you want a 1/2 HP or better VFD (Variable Frequency Drive) that accepts the type of mains you have available and provides the appropriate voltage for your motor, such as [this](http://www.globalindustrial.ca/p/motors/Motors-Gearmotors/ac-parallel-motors/leeson-ac-controls-sub-micro-series-vfd-drive-ip20-1-or-3ph-1-2hp-200-230v?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=CNfFlIO7ntACFUUdaQod9-oKjg) one.

[image]

There are cheaper ones available- this one is a good brand name and safety agency listed.

The VFD determines the motor rotor position using back-EMF measurements and synthesizes a 3-phase output waveform of variable frequency and voltage to properly drive the motor over a wide range of RPM and torques.

The device you linked to is only suitable for single phase motors with certain types of loads.